# Stop label callouts from crossing the polygon

Tags: qgis, labeling

Can you stop the label callouts from unnecessary crossing the polygons and just go outwards.

Picture below is with the suggested change
and below that is placing of labels

[image: Screendump]
[image: Screendump2]
[image: Screendump3]

Comment: "label-lines" : labels callouts !

Comment: If you're asking about improved label placement, and not about callout lines, please provide your label placement settings.

Comment: Hope I copy the right place, is it possible to control the ladels so that they are always outside?

Answer (score 2):

Change the anchor point of the callout lines from `pole of inaccessibility` to `border`.

[image]

Comment: There isn't any solution that's solves all the crossing callout lines?